# Is there are more elegant way of getting arbitrary javascript objects by id, when checkboxes are marked?

Tags: knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray, computed-observable

Wannt to give the user the possibility to select people via checkboxes in a list.

This sample works, but I would like to know, if you would do it the same way.

The main problem is, that javascript arbitrary objects cannot be compared against easily. So there must be a mapping.

Is this ok so? I don't want to create a custom-binding for this, where I could defined an Id field in the binding.

```
  function Person(id, name, age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  function Party(id, name, persons) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.persons = ko.observableArray(persons);
    this.persons_checked = ko.observableArray(); //<--- for the checkboxes
    this.persons_checked.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var mapped = [];
    mapped = $.map(newValue, function(id) { 
        return $.grep(listOfPeople, function(n) { return n.id == id; });  });
    self.persons(mapped);

});
```

}

Complete Sample here: http://jsbin.com/ukipek/6/edit

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use knockoutjs 3.x and not 2.x, and it is magically done !

I've taken your example and modified it:

The HTML part:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: party.name"></h1>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.party.persons_checked, attr: {value: id}">
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the JS part:

```
function Person(id, name, age) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.age = age;
}

function Party(id, name, persons) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.persons = ko.observableArray(persons);
    self.persons_checked = ko.observableArray();
}

var listOfPeople = [
new Person(1, 'Fred', 25),
new Person(2, 'Joe', 60),
new Person(3, 'Sally', 43)];

var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.party = new Party(1, "Weihnachtsfeier1", []);
    this.people = ko.observableArray(listOfPeople);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

No more mappings, knockoutjs handles everything alone :-)

You can have a look at this jsbin if you want : http://jsbin.com/sasuvuwabu/1/edit

Hope that helps !